# Contact Form plugin - different recipients per locale

Tags: localization, plugin-contactform

What is the best way to define different sendto emails addresses for the ContactForm plugin, depending on the locale the site is currently viewed in?

I am setting up a multilanguage site, and the clients want to have different emails for each language version.

So far I figure a possible way would be to have separate, localized contactform templates, and in each of them define a dynamically-added recipient. But I wondered if there's a better option, e.g. locale-specific options in craft/config/contactform.php?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could write a plugin, which hooks in the contact form's [`onBeforeSend` event](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/contactform/services/ContactFormService.php#L86-L89), and modifies the recipients.

Here's an absolute bare-bones solution which does exactly that (not tested in any way whatsoever):

```
<?php namespace Craft;

class ExamplePlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    // Standard plugin methods omitted for brevity...

    public function init()
    {
        craft()->on('contactform.beforeSend', function (Event &$event) {
            $event->toEmail = 'john@doe.com';
        });
    }
}
```

Whether or not this is "officially" supported is unclear.

The fact it's an event (as opposed to a hook) might suggest not, *but* the contact form does check whether any listeners modified the event data, as evidenced by its [check of the `isValid` property](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/contactform/services/ContactFormService.php#L30).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a simple piece of code in /craft/config/contactform.php

```
namespace Craft;

switch (CRAFT_LOCALE) {
    case 'en': $cf_toEmail = 'english@domain.co.uk'; break;
    case 'de': $cf_toEmail = 'german@domain.de'; break;
    // .....
    default:   $cf_toEmail = null;
}

return array(
    'toEmail' => $cf_toEmail,
    'prependSender' => '('.craft()->request->getPost('fromEmail').')',
);
```

`prependSender` in the return array was to troubleshoot another shortcoming that my clients do not like in the emails the CF plugin sends - that there is nowhere to see the `fromEmail` in the received email - it is only in the Reply-To header.

And I chose the config file over the plugin, as it's simpler and less code.